# Variation of Node Add Screen?

Tags: 7, nodes

How do I create a second version a node add page?

For example if have node/add and I want node/add-quick?

Some fields of the required fields form node/add  would be missing or not required on node/add-quick.

I know node add fields can be hidden based on user role or other variables but how do I create an entirely new page with a select set of fields.

Comment: Hm... one way you could do this would be EntityForm + Rules. Create the Form, then use Rules for its submission to create a node. Although any solution here feels heavy handed. Would it be easier to un-require the fields and add publishing states to them?

Answer (score 0):

with [panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) you can select witch fields display and just do not add fields that you dont want, do not place "complete node form", also you can control what contentypes node/add form overrides.
If you do not use panels module you can add a custom module with the following code (D7), replace uppercase letters with your data. This code only affect "your_form_id", to find your form_id, inspect an element (right click on your form) and look for it.

```
 //if form id is YOURFORM_form hide elements
 function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      global $user;
        $uuid = $user->uid;              
  /*  check that user is NOT admin (No1) */
     if ($uuid !='1') {

        if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
            hide($form['field_YOUR_FIELD']); // hides field to all but admin user
            $form['body']['#format'] = 'plain_text'; // forces body format to plain text
            //displays field in form, but disabled
            $form['YOUR_SECOND_FIELD']['#disabled'] = TRUE; 
        }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Can panels module create a duplicate node/add page?

Comment: yes, panels is a very powerfull module, look in google for video tutorials, not the quick ones, a series about 10 lessons or so.

Answer (score 0):

If D7, try Advanced Form Block module (AFB) for add-quick ajax node creations where forms can be a block in sidebar or content block, top or bottom of region, displayed only for admin. Cheat and hide some fields with css, or tweak the module as alternate to building from scratch.   I have used it for 4 different content type creation forms, side by side in a 4 column footer region, for rapid content creation.